# How Do I Know A Document With Expires Attribute Got Deleted?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm implementing some verification procedures in Node.js. I had each verification stored in my MongoDB by Mongoose, and set a expires attribute for it, so it will be deleted after some time. Like this

```
var verification = new Schema({
  // something else
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    expires: '1d',
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

But I want to know when that doc is deleted. So I can do something else, like deleting the docs related with that verification. I've tried using `post()` hooks,

```
verification.post('remove', function(){
  // do something else
};
```

But it seems this won't work, since it's on application level. The doc is deleted by MongoDB  directly, so `remove()` won't be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't know when the document will be deleted because MongoDB removes the expired documents in a background task. There is currently no way to check which documents were deleted.

If you really need this functionality, you can create a background job that will delete documents from your own collections every 60 seconds and then notify you which documents were deleted.